# Automatic power on at preset time

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, automation, power-on

Is there a way or app that allows to program a schedule for automatic power on/off on the phone for android 4.x?

I know that in the settings there is a similar option, however it allows to define only **ONE** schedule for power on and **ONE** for power off, while I'd be looking for more flexibility.

Edit:

I'm using an HTC desire 310 with android 4.2, and my use case would be like turn the phone off at 11pm when going to sleep, and then having it automatically turn on at 6.50am, so the alarm set at 7am can regularly wake me up.

Comment: If I understand it right, For an example; Power off the phone at midnight, But have it turn back on at 7am? Don't think that's possible from the little bit of google searching I did. Once the device is off, its off. If you want the device to reboot at a certain time. That can be done with an app, Tasker can do it. Not entirely sure what you are asking though. Also a screenshot of your schedule app/setting would be helpful, as well as the phone make/model.

Comment: @jer3my please see my edit

Comment: Ahh I gotcha. This app is a little older but was still getting reviews til 2014 it looks like. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monocube.powerschedule&hl=en It might work for your device, but it still doesnt turn the phone off completely. You could use an app like Tasker to automatically set the phone to silent, airplane mode, plus any number of other options. And if you pair it with something like greenify, it will kill apps you tell it too that normally run in the background. Is there any reason you want the phone off at night? Just wondering

Comment: It'd be just to let the phone "rest" a little too XD